# Unit Impulse as derivate of rectangular pulse

Tags: derivatives, signal-processing, dirac-delta

I have an exercise, I graphically understood that the relationship is true, but I have a little doubt on how to prove it.
$$ \frac{d\Pi(t)}{dt} = \delta\left(t + \frac{1}{2}\right) - \delta\left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right) $$
where $ \delta(t) $ is the Dirac impulse, and  $ \Pi=\{ 1 $ if $|t| \leq \frac{1}{2} $ , 0 else $ \}$

I have to prove that this relationship is true. Can u help me? Thanks!

Comment: Write $\Pi(t)$ as the sum of two scaled and shifted unit step functions and then take the derivative.  Or you could just integrate both sides of your given equation.

Comment: It depends the way $\delta$ has been defined for you. Have you for example seen distributions ?

Comment: Really thanks guys! I solved the problem with Andy solution